# Required Help to join three entity on different columns using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, join

#### Updated Question

I have 3 tables like

```
Section (id, title, url)//id is Primary key
Category (id, title)//id is Primary key
SubCategory (id, title)//id is Primary key
```

Here, I want to join these table as in simple query like

```
Select * From Category cat, Section se, SubCategory subCat  WHERE
 subCat.id=23456  AND subCat.category=cat.id  AND subCat.section = se.id
```

How can I achieve the above query using Criteria in Hibernate? Can
anyone help me on this?

#### Adding my question here

My entity Files are as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="section")
public class SectionEntity{
  private int id;
  private String title;
  //Getter & setter method
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class CategoryEntity{
  private int id;
  private String title;
  private Set<SubCategoryEntity> subCategory;
  //Getter & setter method
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="category", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  public Set<SubCategoryEntity> getSubCategory(){
    return this.subCategory;
  }
}
```

---

#### Updated SubCategoryEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="subcategory")
public class SubCategoryEntity{
  private int id;
  private String title;

  private Set<SectionEntity> sectionEntity;

  //Getter & setter method
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  public Set<SectionEntity> getSectionEntity(){
    this.section;
  }
}
```

---

#### Steps to use Hibernate Criteria as:

> Step 1: Creating criteria for Category Entity
>           Criteria categoriesCriteria = session.createCriteria(CategoriesEntity.class, "categoryEntity");
>
> Step 2: Creating aliases of SubCategoryEntity and SectionEntity
>           categoriesCriteria.createAlias("categoryEntity.subCategoryEntity", "subCatEntity");
>           categoriesCriteria.createAlias("subCatEntity.sectionsEntity", "subCatSectionEntity");
>
> Step 3: Set the property in projection list
>
> Step 4: Add Restriction as: 
>           categoriesCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("subCatEntity.id", primCategoryId));
>
> Step 5:    Set projection property into CategoryEntity Criteria
>           categoriesCriteria.setProjection(projPropList);
>
> Step 6:    Getting result
>           categoriesCriteria.list();

#### My resulting query displaying as:

```
select this_.id as y0_, this_.title as y1_, this_.sef_url as y2_, subcatenti1_.id as y3_, subcatenti1_.title as y4_, subcatenti1_.sef_url as y5_
from jos_categories this_
inner join jos_subcategories subcatenti1_ on this_.id=subcatenti1_.category
inner join jos_sections subcatsect2_ on subcatenti1_.id=subcatsect2_.id
where subcatenti1_.id=?
```

#### But I have required expected query as:

```
select this_.id as y0_, this_.title as y1_, this_.sef_url as y2_, subcatenti1_.id as y3_, subcatenti1_.title as y4_, subcatenti1_.sef_url as y5_
from jos_categories this_
inner join jos_subcategories subcatenti1_ on this_.id=subcatenti1_.category
inner join jos_sections subcatsect2_ on subcatenti1_.section=subcatsect2_.id
where subcatenti1_.id=?
```

How Can I achieve this, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Same question on Linkedin, please check below links


https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Required-Help-join-three-entity-148952.S.5914980553664253953?trk=groups_most_recent-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmr_148952

Comment: possible duplicate of [Required help to join 3 tables (on different columns) using Hibernate Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721924/required-help-to-join-3-tables-on-different-columns-using-hibernate-criteria)

Comment: Hi Frazz,

I did not get your point, please specify your answer, if you know.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up this mess. Would you please read through the Help center. That may help you understand better how questions and answers work here on SO. The 2 questions are practically identical. Only one must exist, with all the relevant info, and maybe some better formatting.

Comment: Frazz,

I have deleted the previous question.

Comment: Ok... this all looks much better now. I formatted the question a bit. Thanks for working on it. Now wait for people with the right expertise to see it and answer it ;) (I'm good in Java, but never used Hibernate)

Comment: Can you detail the projection list in step 3 please ?

Answer (score 0):

In your SubCategoryFile make change like this,

1) remove "private int section;" and all getter and setter method of this.

2) and use this

```
       @JoinColumn(name="section", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       public Set<SectionEntity> getSection(){
          this.section;
           }
```

and then try to run. I hope it will work

Comment: In SectionEntity which refers to section table, there is no 'section' column/fields.
Also, I missed to update my SubCategoryEntity, the object of SectionEntity should be sectinoEntity not section. That was my mistake which I miss to update.

Comment: give me the relation(foreign keys) of your tables.

Comment: No Foreign keys in the tables. Now, please tell me how can I achieve this?